# Large numbers from string to int in c++

Tags: c++, string, int, long-integer

I did some search before I ask this question. I tried using `unsigned int` then use `strtoul` to convert from string to `unsigned int`.
Even simple code like

```
 unsigned int num = 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

This code still not working. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
     unsigned int num = 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
     unsigned int num2 = 1;
     unsigned int ans = num + num2;
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
 string num1 = "99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;"
 string num2 = "1"
 string conv_ans;

 unsigned int conv1 = strtoul(num1); 
 unsigned int conv2 = strtoul(num2); 
 unsigned int ans = conv1 + conv2;

 conv_ans = ans;
```

Thank you!

Comment: So you're looking for a big-integer library in C++? The highest value an `unsigned int` can hold is usually 4294967295 or 18446744073709551615, so there is no way to store 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999... in an `unsigned int`.

Comment: Nomatter your code gymnastics, an int will never* store a number that large. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx

Comment: @user4799188: even 64-bit CPUs just don't have large enough registers to handle such large numbers in single operations, so maths operations have to be synthesised from several smaller steps by the software and are considerably slower. Most languages have their main arithmetic support restricted to what their hardware can do at full speed, but C++ has libraries (e.g. [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)) letting you use arbitrarily large numbers. (One of the few good things I can say about Python: it supporting this out of the box, but then it's so slow at everything why care about this....)

Comment: Alternatively, use `double` (or even `long double` if your compiler offers it) - though that will have some rounding errors in the least significant digits.

Comment: Computers do have some limitations. The amount of data that can be stored depends on the data type. An integer (signed or unsigned) can never store a value that large. You could store an arbitrarily long string (or character array) of digits so long as you have the memory to do so, but it wont be able to be considered an integer. Integers are 16 bits so unsigned integers have a max of 4294967295 or in hex 0xffffffff

Comment: @element11: `s/16 bits/often 32 bits/`

Comment: @element11 int is mostly 32 bits nowadays except on some 16-bit-and-less embedded systems. You can hardly find a 16-bit PC anymore

Comment: a keyword for you: [tag:bigint]

Answer (score 3):

> I want to be able to do something like this

You can't.

`unsigned int` cannot store values greater than 
`std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()`.  Often that's around 4 billion.

To store and manage integers of arbitrary size, such as the number of atoms in the Milky Way (roughly your number), you will need to use a "big int" library, such as [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in @Drew's answer, there is no C++ built-in type that can store integers as large as you want. A quick and easy to use multi-precision library comes with [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) and it's called [Boost.Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html). It is [reasonably fast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints.html), and writing code that uses it is a breeze (no need for precompiled headers or other shared libraries, just `-I /path/to/boost`). For example, computing factorial(1000) (which is a really big number) looks like

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   using namespace boost::multiprecision;

   cpp_int u = 1; // multi-precision integer
   for(int i = 1; i < 1000; ++i) // compute 1000!
      u *= i;

   std::cout << u << std::endl; // prints 1000!
}
```

One advantage of Boost.Multiprecision is that it is very well integrated with the C++ stream libraries, and you can basically use it as a built in type. The library has also support for floating point numbers, rationals etc (see the documentation).

Furthermore, Boost is one of the most "standardized" C++ libraries (many features of Boost ended up in C++11), and it is highly used, so you may give it a try.

Comment: Wow, that is very seamless code.  Time for me to learn a new boost lib.

Comment: Say `string s="12577777768457677219765765712433333434"`, can I convert into integer with boost library (like we do using `stoi`)?

Answer (score 0):

Use these set of functions according to your needs

```cpp
  stoi(num1);   // to int
  stol(num1);   // to long
  stoll(num1);  // to long long
  stoul(num1);  // to unsigned long
  stoull(num1); // to unsigned long long
```